# MySQL: Use a single Column to show as multiple select column in single row

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider these example tables

[image]

[image]

E_id in Table1 is a primary key. From and Assign_to are foreign keys referenced with E_id.

I want to show a table like this:

[image]

I am not sure how I can implement it. Please share the SQL query which returns the desired table.

Comment: How are we supposed to know which work names to return, e.g. Reading comes from nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `JOIN` to `Table1` twice:

```
SELECT
    t2.work_name,
    t1f.E_name AS `From`,
    t1a.E_Name AS `Assign_to`
FROM Table2 t2
INNER JOIN Table1 t1f
    ON t1f.E_id = t2.`from`
INNER JOIN Table1 t1a
    ON t1a.E_id =t2.Assign_to
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve that problem with a simple temp table. It is not the most sophisticated way to solve it, but the solution is easy to comprehend.

The step are as followed:

- Create a table with all data from table2
- Add 2 columns to that table to store the name values for from and Assign_to
- Update the columns with the name values from table1
- Select your Data

**MySQL-Code**

```
-- create temp-table
CREATE TABLE table2_temp 
SELECT  * FROM  table2;

-- add columns to enrich table with E_name from table1
ALTER TABLE table2_temp 
 ADD COLUMN E_name_from VARCHAR (125),
 ADD COLUMN E_name_assign_to VARCHAR (125);

-- update temp-table with names from table1

 -- for E_name_from
UPDATE table2_temp A
INNER JOIN table1 B ON (A.`from` = E_id)
SET A.E_name_from = B.E_name;

 -- for E_name_assign_to
UPDATE table2_temp A
INNER JOIN table1.B ON (A.Assign_to = E_id)
SET A.E_name_assign_to = B.E_name;

-- now you can select your date from the temp-table
SELECT
    work_name,
    E_name_from AS `From`,
    E_name_assign_to AS `Assign_to`
FROM
    table2_temp;

-- drop table after work is done
drop table if exists table2_temp ;
```